# Best approach to time-series data in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, hbase, time-series

Via a `stored procedure` in `SQL Server 2008`, I am trying to show the number of transactions from the past 7 days, and then compare those numbers to a 7 day period a year ago.  Additionally, I'd like to be able to show month-to-date versus month-to-date a year ago.  Or this month to last month.  Etc.  Essentially, `time-series` data.

I've got a table with all the individual transactions.  The two options I can think of are:

1. Calculate each individual day or month and return the result set
   at run time.
2. Calculate each invididual day and put the result
   into a table.  Update that daily.  Create another table for weeks. 
   Another table for months.  Each day, add a record or update the
   existing record.  That certainly will make the query faster, since
   the data is already calculated.  However, if I had to make updates to previous days (taking into account returns/cancels)

Note:  This is an internal application, so it won't see thousands of requests a minute.

What is the best way to return this type of data?

The other alternative I've thought about is using `HBase OpenTSDB` via Option 2, but seems like it's the same process.

Comment: How much data are we talking about?

Comment: Total table size in the 10s of millions.  Per day - 10s of thousands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be either misunderstanding the question, or need to see your table schema (or something similar), but I see this as a simple `SELECT COUNT(*)...WHERE DATE BETWEEN [2Dates]`.  If all you need to do is count transactions that is.

Answer (score 0):

I generally agree with @Justin. One way to expedite it would be with a query based on this idea:

```
SELECT 
   datepart(yy, TranDate)  Year
  ,datepart(mm, TranDate)  Month
  ,datepart(dd, TranDate)  Day
  ,count(*)
 from TranTable
 where TranDate between @Start and @Stop
 group by
   datepart(yy, TranDate)  --  Year
  ,datepart(mm, TranDate)  --  Month
  ,datepart(dd, TranDate)  --  Day
 order by
   datepart(yy, TranDate)  --  Year
  ,datepart(mm, TranDate)  --  Month
  ,datepart(dd, TranDate)  --  Day
```

You'd have to modify this for your system and requirements.

Setting up a separate table that gets updated every day (or so) is a standard data warehousing tactic. This can be useful if you don't want "reporting" queries locking up your transactional system, or if you need tables specifically designed to support such queries (for performance, ususally). But if

> This is an internal application, so it won't see thousands of requests
>   a minute.

then warhousing sounds like overkill.

Comment: If you're going to group by day, why not just `GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, TranDate)`?

Comment: Because I wrote that query template in SQL 2000 : )   [The full form actually incorporates week, hour, minute, etc., allowing me to pick and choose just which "time band" I'm aggregating over. But yes, if you're only ever dealing with calendar days, converting to the `DATE` datatype would be simpler.]

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with your option Number 2.

You have an [OLTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_transaction_processing) database schema and you want to run [OLAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing) queries.

I don't think it's overkill to split them out.